# Camera preview - gingerbread

Tags: android, camera, preview

The following code works on froyo, I can see the preview and records on gingerbread the screen is black until you press record, it does record fine but the preview won't work

```
package com.exercise.AndroidVideoCapture;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AndroidVideoCapture extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Button myButton;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean recording;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    recording = false;

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    initMediaRecorder();

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SurfaceView myVideoView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    surfaceHolder = myVideoView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
}

private Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener 
= new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(recording){
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            finish();
        }else{
            mediaRecorder.start();
            recording = true;
            myButton.setText("STOP");
        }
    }};

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    prepareMediaRecorder();
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void initMediaRecorder(){
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
}

private void prepareMediaRecorder(){
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem here. 
As a workaround, I'm calling `mediaRecorder.start()` if the SDK version is greater than `8`.
It's ugly and probably not optimal, but I haven't found any better solution.

Comment: If you don't call mediaRecorder.start() on the button click it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

To see the camera preview before setting the MediaRecorder you have to open a Camera object and start preview. MediaRecorder does this also, but only once you prepare it, so if you are not calling that code until your user clicks record you will just have a blank screen. Look here for a simple intro: http://integratingstuff.com/2010/10/18/writing-code-that-captures-videos-on-android/

You can also browse the Android Camera code:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera